# How can I make setOnMouseDragOver work in this case?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a battleship game.

Here's a link to the code: [Battleship](https://gist.github.com/tmjonker/e110fa7aa242df3942ae822c811ab737)

Basically, when you click on one of the ship buttons(battleship, cruiser, submarine, etc.) a Rectangle pops up on the screen.  You can move this rectangle around the screen by clicking on it and dragging the mouse around.  The class that adds all of the event handlers to the Rectangle can be found in class MouseGestures.java.

Event Handlers are added to the GridPane in the GameGUI.java class starting at line 82.

Basically, I'm trying to find the index of whatever node you drag this object over in the GridPane.  I'm able to accomplish this without dragging, by applying setOnMouseEntered to each node in the gridpane, but when I try to utilize setOnMouseDragEntered, I get nothing.

Would anyone have an idea for how to get this to work?

Just to reiterate, I want to print in the console the index of each gridpane when I drag and move a node over the nodes contained in the gridpane.

These are the event handlers I have applied to the nodes in the gridpane.

```
    for (int i=0; i<=11; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<=11; j++) {

            int colIndex = i;
            int rowIndex = j;

            grid2[i][j] = new Rectangle();
            grid2[i][j].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            grid2[i][j].setFill(null);
            grid2[i][j].setStrokeWidth(1);
            grid2[i][j].setWidth(30);
            grid2[i][j].setHeight(30);
            //Prints index of each grid2[][] upon mouse entry.
            grid2[i][j].setOnMouseEntered( e -> {
                System.out.printf("Mouse entered cell [%d, %d]%n", colIndex, rowIndex);
            });
            //Does not work! Want to print index of each grid2[][] upon mouse drag enter.
            grid2[i][j].setOnMouseDragEntered( e -> {
                System.out.printf("Mouse entered cell [%d, %d]%n", colIndex, rowIndex);
            });
            //Does not work! Want to print index of each grid2[][] upon mouse drag over.
            grid2[i][j].setOnMouseDragOver( e -> {
                System.out.printf("Mouse entered cell [%d, %d]%n", colIndex, rowIndex);
            });
```

These are the event handlers for the object you create when you push one of the buttons.

```
private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = event -> {
    if (event.getSource() instanceof Rectangle) {
        shipSelected = (Rectangle) (event.getSource());

        dragContext.x = shipSelected.getTranslateX() - shipSelected.getWidth()/2;
        dragContext.y = shipSelected.getTranslateY() - shipSelected.getHeight()/2;
    }
};


private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDragDetectedEventHandler = event -> {
    shipSelected.startFullDrag();

    System.out.println("startfulldrag");
};


private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = event -> {
    if (event.getSource() instanceof Rectangle) {
        shipSelected = (Rectangle) (event.getSource());

        shipSelected.setX(dragContext.x + event.getX());
        shipSelected.setY(dragContext.y + event.getY());

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `Rectangle` you move around mouse transparent with `setMouseTransparent(true)` while you are dragging it.

```
private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDragDetectedEventHandler = event -> {
    shipSelected.startFullDrag();
    shipSelected.setMouseTransparent(true)
    System.out.println("startfulldrag");
};
```

Otherwise, the Rectangle is always the top-most element under your mouse pointer, and you will not get dragEntered events from the elements below (i.e. the grid).

Of course, do not forget to set mouse transparency back to false, when you ended dragging.

Comment: WOW! Thanks.  I've literally been messing with this stupid thing for like 4 days.  And thats all it took.  I appreciate it.  Thanks again.

Comment: With nice feedback like this, it is a pleasure to help